# Multiple Posgres databases in CircleCI 2.0

Tags: postgresql, circleci, circleci-2.0

How can I have my Postgres image create more than one database? For example, I want to do something like this:

```
- image: circleci/postgres:9.6.7-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: db_test
      POSTGRES_DB: db_special
```

Is there a way to do this? And if not, how can I go about creating the second database with the same roles as the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Developer Advocate at CircleCI*

I see three options for you.

1. Extend the PostgreSQL Docker image yourself and have it created the additional databases you need by default.
2. Create the additional databases on the fly through your app (should just be one SQL line) or by using the PostgreSQL CLI (which you'd need to install in the container).
3. Use two or more PostgreSQL containers at the same time, one for each database. You'd also then need to change the default hostname for one of them. The first would be located at `localhost` and the second by a name you set.

Here's an example for #3:

```
- image: circleci/my-main-image:latest
- image: circleci/postgres:9.6.7-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: db_test
- image: circleci/postgres:9.6.7-alpine
    name: pg2
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: db_special
```

Comment: option 2 looks the easiest: `psql  -c "CREATE DATABASE db_test WITH TEMPLATE db_special  OWNER user;"`

Comment: I ended up going with the second option - worked perfectly.

Comment: Great. I'm happy to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the second option.

If you´re not in the docker image bash, but in the root machine/container you can also run:

```
psql -h localhost -p PORT-U root -d FIRST_DB -c "create database NEW_DB;"
```

PORT: normally 5432

FIRST_DB: in your case db_test

NEW_DB: in your case db_special

Again this is one addition because normally on circle ci you run your command line from your first image not from the Postgres image.

If you take a look in https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/postgres-config/

They have examples with 2 images: first with go + postgres or java + postgres.